# Can I use one table field value as second table field name in mysql select query?

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, codeigniter

Scenario:

**Field names of Table1 named as testtable**

id,name,size,width,height

**Field names of Table2 named as errortable**

id,desc,field1,field2,operator

**Values of errortable**

```
+----+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+----------+
| id |                desc                 | field1 | field2 | operator |
+----+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+----------+
|  1 | size should not greater than width  | size   | width  | >        |
|  2 | size should not greater than height | size   | height | >        |
|  3 | with should be equal to height      | width  | height | <>       |
+----+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+----------+
```

now i want to check from testtable:

1. count all those records where size > width
2. count all those records where size > height
3. count all those records where width <> height.

**Required Output**

```
+-------------------------------------+-------+
|              errorname              | count |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| size should not greater than width  |     6 |
| size should not greater than height |     2 |
| with should be equal to height      |     3 |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
```

is it possible to do like this?

**current query:**

select desc,(select count(*) as "Total Errors" from testtable where errortable.field1 errortable.operator errortable.field2 ) from errortable group by id

Comment: MySQL or Postgeslq? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: anyone, i need in both

Comment: The reason they're called __relational__ databases is because they're all about __relations__ between tables, but there is no relation between these two tables

Comment: relation is not possible, i have an error list and i want to check many errors exist in another table, thats it,

Comment: Clearly a relationship is possible, otherwise you wouldnt want to link the data. Can you explain CLEARLY what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Listen, i have two table one having data and second having errors list. In errors list table i have errors decription and by which column i can check that error. so how to make a relation between these two tables.

Comment: I think you will need to use php to build up a dynamic query to get the 2nd queries from one based on the 1st. It might be possible to build a function in MySQL to do this instead.

Comment: it is not possible from single query?

Comment: No, because you are trying to use a field value as a field name and I can't think of a way of doing this in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all who commented, i have got my answer within your comments and achieved this scenario by tackling with some code in php.